# Pressing tab on a web form automatically submits the form on firefox

Tags: forms, firefox, submit

I'm developing an application with full JS stack, and when we did a cross browser test, firefox automatically submits my web form each time I press the tab key.

Here's a list of the tools the application is using on the Front-End:

1. Jquery
2. Node.Js + ExpressJs
3. Stylus (As css compiler)
4. GETUIKIT (http://www.getuikit.com) as my css framework

Here's what I've done so far:

1. I tried turning off all stylings, and still happens (So it was not the css framework)
2. I tried disabling the getuikit's js and it still happens (so it was not the framework js library)

Has this ever happened to anybody in firefox?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Please consider showing the code that you think might be causing this. While the error could be inherent in the technology, its more likely to be a problem with what you have written. As is, we likely can't reproduce the issue, and so can't help you fix it!